# Help recovering data from Google Chrome Sync - it didn't download my stuff

Tags: google-chrome, google-sync

I **had to reinstall Linux** due to some errors.

Anyway, so what I did was make sure that **chrome sync said up to date as of less than a minute ago**, and that all of my stuff was being sent up.

Then I reinstalled, now after **logging into chrome sync NONE of the stuff has been downloaded**. I waited a while, still the same. **NO preferences, extensions, bookmarks, etc.**

The most important thing is extensions and their settings, because my bookmarks are saved in Xmarks as well so no issue there.

Whoever can help me with this is a legend among the internet, because I had stuff saved in my extensions that is otherwise unrecoverable :(

Comment: Did you try it on a Windows machine? Maybe that could be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. No luck with any of them though.

Ended up just starting from scratch - xmarks saved my open tabs and bookmarks though so happy about that :)

Answer (score 1):

We're missing a bit of information about what you've attempted to do and what you haven't, but here's something to start with.

Make sure you have enabled Sync correctly.

Quote from Google Chrome Support websit

> 1.Open Google Chrome.
>
> 2.Click the wrench icon  on the browser toolbar. Mac users: If you don't see the wrench icon, go to >the menu bar at the top of your screen and click Chrome.
>
> 3.Select Options (Preferences on Mac and Linux).
>
> 4.Click the Personal Stuff tab.
>
> 5.In the "Sync" section, click Set up sync.
>
> 6.Sign in to your Google Account in the dialog that appears. Don't have an account? Learn how to >create one
>
> 7.In the "Set up sync" dialog that appears, choose what you want to sync. 
>          ◦Sync everything: Select the "Keep everything in sync" option.
>          ◦Choose specific items to sync: Select the "Choose what to sync" option, then select the >checkboxes for the items you want to sync. 
>                    ■Apps from the Chrome Web Store
>                    ■AutoFill data (except for credit card numbers)
>                    ■Bookmarks
>                    ■Extensions from the Chrome Web Store (except those containing plug-ins) 
>                    ■Preferences 
>                    ■Themes
>
> 8.Click OK.
>
> 9.You'll see a confirmation message once Google Chrome has finished copying your browser data to >your Google Account. Click OK in the message.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome syncs are stored in your Google Docs account. You should have a folder in gdocs called 'Google Chrome' containing whatever was last sync'd.